# Does Invisible mode still allow you to gain hours in-game?

Tags: steam

Invisible status (which can be access via Friends -> Invisible) has been released to the Steam client. I'm wondering - even though from your friend's perspective, you're offline - will you still gain hours in the game you're playing in?

Comment: I would say this is really simple to test - go invisible, take note of how much time you have in a game already, play the game for an hour, and then see if the time changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should still be gaining playtime. Hours played, achievements, and etc are not related to your friends/chat status in any way.

Invisible mode is simply a way to appear offline while still being able to game, and you can still chat with your friends online if you decide to do so.